# Autocomplete in Aptana

Tags: javascript, jquery, eclipse, ide, aptana

I am using Aptana studio 3 for web programming. Also I use jQuery for the same purpose. The problem is with the autocomplete in Aptana. For instance I am getting this:

```
$('div').click(function() {
     ${0:
\}});
```

Instead of this:

```
$('div').click(function() {

});
```

Maybe there is some way to change it (the same happens with other jquery aoutocomplete options).
Thanks!

Comment: Similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4762316/how-do-i-change-the-autocomplete-key-in-aptana

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similar thing happening when trying to type `$.ajax...` Aptana would insert `Array(...`

I discovered I needed to install the jQuery bundle!

Open the commands menu > bundle development > install bundle

In the "select bundle to install" window, choose jQuery and hit OK. That's it! You may need to restart Aptana.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've did it before, that what gave me the option of this bed Autosuggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use latest *vsdoc* file and use it for code completion. The latest one could be found [here](http://appendto.com/community/jquery-vsdoc/). Also please check following related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721124/how-to-enable-jquery-support-in-aptana-studio-3).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will work for you, but you can try it if you're only using JavaScript and jQuery. https://github.com/JockiHendry/aptanastudio-contentassist-patch